# Ошибка при установке/запуске Homestead

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, homestead

VirtualBox, vagrant встали, все отлично. Но при выполнение vagrant up
Вываливается ошибка:

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed for /dev/vboxnetctl: Inappropriate ioctl for devic
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg*)" at line 94 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

На ubuntu раньше не сидел, но работа требует настроить среду на ubuntu...
В чем может быть ошибка? Уже все перепробовал, все инструкции перечитал...

Answer (score 0):

У вас установлена последняя версия VirtualBox? 
Похоже на вашу проблему на англоязычном stackoverflow.com
[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069908/vboxmanage-error-failed-to-create-the-host-only-adapter)
В решении говорят что нужно открыть VirtualBox и остановить все машины. Затем перезагрузить VirtualBox:

```
sudo service virtualbox restart
```

Также рекомендуют удалить VirtualBox и поставить последнюю версию.